# conan make generator does not set CONAN_CXXFLAGS as expected

Tags: c++, makefile, package-managers, conan

When running `conan install . -s arch=x86` on an `x86_64` System, I expect a compiler option like `CONAN_CXXFLAGS_MYLIB=-m32` in the generated `conanbuildinfo.mak` file, but there is no such an option.

First, the contents of the `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
mylib/1.0@demo/dev

[generators]
make
```

Here is the output of the `install` command (cmake has special treatment, because it is only a tool):

```
$ conan install . -s cmake:arch=x86_64  -s arch=x86
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=9
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
cmake:arch=x86_64
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

conanfile.txt: Installing package
Requirements
    mylib/1.0@demo/dev from local cache - Cache
Packages
    mylib/1.0@demo/dev:eb79ce42f6e6b4359bd7d0a65a238a4dae953257 - Cache
'''
Cross-build from 'Linux:x86_64' to 'Linux:x86'
Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
mylib/1.0@demo/dev: Already installed!
conanfile.txt: Generator make created conanbuildinfo.mak
conanfile.txt: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generated conaninfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generated graphinfo
```

The generated makfe file looks like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
#             Makefile variables from Conan Dependencies            #
#-------------------------------------------------------------------#

CONAN_ROOT_MYLIB ?=  \
/home/username/.conan/data/mylib/1.0/demo/dev/package/eb79ce42f6e6b4359bd7d0a65a238a4dae953257

CONAN_SYSROOT_MYLIB ?=  \


CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_MYLIB +=  \
/home/username/.conan/data/mylib/1.0/demo/dev/package/eb79ce42f6e6b4359bd7d0a65a238a4dae953257/include

CONAN_LIB_DIRS_MYLIB +=  \
/home/username/.conan/data/mylib/1.0/demo/dev/package/eb79ce42f6e6b4359bd7d0a65a238a4dae953257/lib

CONAN_BIN_DIRS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_BUILD_DIRS_MYLIB +=  \
/home/username/.conan/data/mylib/1.0/demo/dev/package/eb79ce42f6e6b4359bd7d0a65a238a4dae953257/

CONAN_RES_DIRS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_LIBS_MYLIB +=  \
mylib

CONAN_SYSTEM_LIBS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_DEFINES_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_CFLAGS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_CXXFLAGS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_SHAREDLINKFLAGS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_EXELINKFLAGS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_FRAMEWORKS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_FRAMEWORK_PATHS_MYLIB +=  \


CONAN_ROOTPATH +=  \
$(CONAN_ROOTPATH_MYLIB)

CONAN_SYSROOT +=  \
$(CONAN_SYSROOT_MYLIB)

CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS +=  \
$(CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_MYLIB)

CONAN_LIB_DIRS +=  \
$(CONAN_LIB_DIRS_MYLIB)

CONAN_BIN_DIRS +=  \
$(CONAN_BIN_DIRS_MYLIB)

CONAN_BUILD_DIRS +=  \
$(CONAN_BUILD_DIRS_MYLIB)

CONAN_RES_DIRS +=  \
$(CONAN_RES_DIRS_MYLIB)

CONAN_LIBS +=  \
$(CONAN_LIBS_MYLIB)

CONAN_DEFINES +=  \
$(CONAN_DEFINES_MYLIB)

CONAN_CFLAGS +=  \
$(CONAN_CFLAGS_MYLIB)

CONAN_CXXFLAGS +=  \
$(CONAN_CXXFLAGS_MYLIB)

CONAN_SHAREDLINKFLAGS +=  \
$(CONAN_SHAREDLINKFLAGS_MYLIB)

CONAN_EXELINKFLAGS +=  \
$(CONAN_EXELINKFLAGS_MYLIB)

CONAN_FRAMEWORKS +=  \
$(CONAN_FRAMEWORKS_MYLIB)

CONAN_FRAMEWORK_PATHS +=  \
$(CONAN_FRAMEWORK_PATHS_MYLIB)

CONAN_SYSTEM_LIBS +=  \
$(CONAN_SYSTEM_LIBS_MYLIB)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Conan knows, that this is a cross-build, it knows the compiler, it builds mylib with 32 bitness (or takes the 32 bit binaries, if found in the repo). So it should be obvious, that my app needs to be compiled with `-m32`.

Why is my expectation wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have found the solution myself. If a `conanfile.py` is used with the autotools/make helper instead of the simple `conanfile.txt`, then it is possible to build the app with `conan build .`, and conan sets all compiler options and defines correctly. Here is an example of such a consumer receipt:

```
from conans import ConanFile, AutoToolsBuildEnvironment
from conans import tools

class AppConan(ConanFile):
    name = "mayapp"
    version = "1.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "mylib/1.0@demo/dev"
    generators = "make", "virtualrunenv"

    def build(self):
        atools = AutoToolsBuildEnvironment(self)
        atools.make()
```

Comment: The thing is that the ``makefile`` generator (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/make.html) creates a file with information from dependencies. Your ``mylib/1.0`` package should have something in its ``package_info()`` method that looks like: ``self.cpp_info.cxx_flags=xxxxx`` (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#cpp-info). Is this the case?

Comment: Basically yes. I think I mixed together two different things: the concept of the conanbuildinfo.* files and the build helper. There is a nice [explanation in the answer to my very same question](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7159#issuecomment-640280948) at GitHub. I think, now I see.